# merging cells in table on a pdf using prawn in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I have a cell with a header, and data beneath it.  I really want that line to go away...is there away to merge top cell with bottom cell?  I thought of a way that seemed hacky was to use formatted text in the cell and make a new line \n in the text string. This just seems hacky, is this how it should be done?

Imagine a box around the bottom two lines, that is what I am aiming for, currently in prawn for rails it is putting a box around each line below ...

**Header Test Here**
Data string of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we have that possibility with prawn. Once, I had the same need, and the solution I found was to eliminate bottom border and top border of the first cell and second respectively.

```
cell_1 = make_cell(:content => "1", :borders => [:top, :left, :right]
cell_2 = make_cell(:content => "2", :borders => [:bottom, :left, :right]
```

Comment: this looks like a better solution than what I implemented, that to stuff data in a cell with line breaks.